# JQuery: Select text between closed tags

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Similar questions have been asked but not quite similar enough!

Given this structure:

`<p class="text">
    <b>1</b>this is point one<b>2</b>this is point two<b>3</b>
</p>`

How would I select the text between the closed tags?  ie "this is point one".

The content is fed back via a JSON call so I can't do much with the structure they're giving me.

Thanks!

Comment: How about "this is point two"?

Comment: @BalusC - I would also like to get that too :P  I'm pretty sure the method will be the same though for either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can replace your `<b>#</b>` to something easier to split on then iterate over the results

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/WGTTH/)

jQuery:

```
var points = $('.text').html().replace(/<b>.<\/b>/g, ',').split(','),
    $results = $('#results');
for (var i in points) {
    if ($.trim(points[i]).length > 0) {
        $results.html($results.html() + points[i] + "<br />");
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution though the @Shawn-Chin had a good solution as well.  This just worked better for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you need access to several of the text nodes, you can extract it all into an array using:

```
var data = $(".text").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && !this.nodeValue.match(/^\s*$/);
}).toArray();
```

You can now access "this is point one" using `data[0].nodeValue` and "this is point two" using `data[1].nodeValue`.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jHhFS/

Note: The additional condition (`!this.nodeValue.match(/^\s*$/)`) filters out text nodes that contain only whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

you can get to that value using .contents(). In your case this would work:

```
alert($(".text").contents().eq(2).text())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try -

```
console.log($('p').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
}));
```

This is taken from - [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery). As stated in the linked question, the solution won't work with IE7, but there is a workaround detailed in the linked question.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/E53HU/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential solution:

```
var nodes = $('p.text')[0].childNodes;
var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        // support older browsers that do not have textContent
        var text = nodes[i].textContent || nodes[i].innerText;
        if ($.trim(text).length > 0) {   // optional - push non-empty strings
            results.push(text);
        }
    }
}
//console.log(results);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/3L8Ze/1/